# Ruby: Is there a gem with method attr_initialize?

Tags: ruby, constructor, initializer, attr-accessor

Is there some popular ruby gem that defines attr_initialize class method, which behaves like following:

```
attr_initialize :attr1, :@attr2, [:@attr3, 1] do |arg4|
  post_initialization(arg4)
end
```

would eval to something equivalent to:

```
attr_accessor :attr1

def initialize(attr1, attr2, attr3 = 1, arg4 = nil)
  @attr1 = attr1
  @attr2 = attr2
  @attr3 = attr3
  post_initialization(arg4)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our [attr_extras](https://github.com/barsoom/attr_extras) is close.

It intentionally doesn't handle default arguments, optional arguments or more than assignment – if you want that, you should probably just define a regular method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that. Just write something like:

```
attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

def initialize(*attrs)
  @attr1, @attr2, @attr3 = attrs
  post_initialization attrs.last
end
```

To me, it doesn't look like too much code.

Comment: You are right that it's not that much code. def attr1; @attr1 end versus attr_reader :attr1 also not much code. So I would benefit from such function, because the code becomes cleaner intent-wise